# How are you used to deploying custom labels with their translations?

Tags: deployment, customlabel, translation

Do you have some custom app to perform this action? Because using change sets it's quite crazy when you need to release e.g. 20 labels and your org already has thousands of others.

I didn't find any other way though. Not even on appexchange...some custom app?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [Translation Workbench](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workbench_overview.htm&type=5)?

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I work for Gearset.*

You can do this really easily in [Gearset](https://gearset.com) as we split up the **Custom Labels** and their associated **Translations**.  Just select **Custom Labels** and **Translations** from the *Metadata comparison filter* and Gearset will find any new items for you to deploy to another org.

Answer (score 0):

I work for Metazoa, the makers of Snapshot. You can easily accomplish this using Snapshot. The product is admin focused so you click-not-code your Custom Label and its Translations deployment.

Try us out (https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016YhyEAE) and if it doesn't work for you, at lease you got your job done during the trial period.

Good luck!

Sridhar